# NIntegrate with vector variable

Tags: numerical-integration

Here's a Gaussian integral

```
NIntegrate[E^-(x^2 + y^2) E^(Sqrt[3] x y), {x,y} ∈ FullRegion[2]]
```

which evaluates to `2π // N`. This is fine for a 2D integral, but to extend this to higher dimensions, it would be more convenient to write it as

```
NIntegrate[E^-r.r E^(Sqrt[3] Most[r].Rest[r]), r ∈ FullRegion[2]]
```

This evaluates to the correct answer, but gives errors saying that `Most` and `Rest` have been applied to the atomic expression `r`. This is presumably happening because `NIntegrate` tries to evaluate its first argument before substituting in values for `r`.

What's the most sensible way to avoid these error messages? (I would rather not just silence them, in case it leads to unanticipated problems with a more complicated example.)

(The same is true with `Integrate` instead, but I suspect there will be different solutions for the two cases, and I'm more interested in `NIntegrate`.)

Comment: It would be nice to learn what is behind the structure of the second factor of your integrand? Where does the integral come from?

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze With appropriately chosen coefficients, this is the partition function of a set of harmonic oscillators coupled by springs. (The second term comes from expanding `(x[i]-x[i+1])^2`.) I just chose `Sqrt[3]` to make the integral give a nice result, but it was obviously a bad choice, as your answer shows.

Answer (score 8):

First of all let us introduce the dimensionalty of the problem explicitly.

In the example case of three dimensions:

```
d = 3;
```

the integration variable is defined as the vector

```
r = Array[vr, d]

(* Out[2]= {vr[1], vr[2], vr[3]} *)
```

and the integral becomes

```
f3[a_] := Integrate[E^(-r.r) E^(a Most[r].Rest[r]), r \[Element] FullRegion[d]]
```

Here we have replaced Sqrt[3] by some real number "a", because, as we shall see, the integral for d = 3 diverges for  a^2>=2.

Examples

```
f3[0]

(* Out[20]= \[Pi]^(3/2) *)

f3[1]

(* Out[21]= Sqrt[2] \[Pi]^(3/2) *)

f3[Sqrt[2]]

(* Out[22]= \[Infinity] *)
```

The more the the integral diverges for a = Sqrt[3]

Writing the integral more explicitly we find the explicit formula for f3[a]:

```
Integrate[E^(-r.r) E^(a Most[r].Rest[r]), {vr[
   1], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {vr[2], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {vr[
   3], -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]

(* Out[26]= ConditionalExpression[(Sqrt[2] \[Pi]^(3/2))/(
 Sqrt[4 - a^2] Sqrt[(-2 + a^2)/(-4 + a^2)]), Re[(-2 + a^2)/(-4 + a^2)] > 0] *)
```

Hence

```
f3x[a_] = %[[1]]

(* Out[27]= (Sqrt[2] \[Pi]^(3/2))/(Sqrt[4 - a^2] Sqrt[(-2 + a^2)/(-4 + a^2)]) *)
```

Answer (score 6):

To address the programming issue of restricting integrand evaluation to vector `r`, you need to define a function with pattern-restricted argument for your integrand.

```
Block[{i},
 i[r_?VectorQ] := E^-r.r E^(Sqrt[3] Most[r].Rest[r]); 
 NIntegrate[i[r], r ∈ FullRegion[2]]
 ]
(*  6.28318  *)
```

Beware that this can come at a cost, although not in the OP's test case.  The use of the pattern-restricted function `i[r]` essentially makes the integrand a numeric black box.  `NIntegrate` cannot symbolically analyze the integrand and choose an appropriate integration method automatically.  The responsibility for this falls on the user.

The use of `?VectorQ` is similar to the use of `?NumericQ` discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037).

Comment: @Miachel E2 Oh yes, this restriction to vectors was what I was looking for (and did "by hand").

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution (with `Sqrt[3]` replaced by `1`):

```
With[{r = Array[r, 2]}, NIntegrate[E^-r.r E^(Most[r].Rest[r]), r ∈ FullRegion[Length[r]]]]
```